# NodeJS SSL where to get .key file

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, https, server

I have bought a SSL Certificate from GlobalSign and I receiver 2 .crt file one is gs_intermediate_ca.crt (Intermediate) and domain_name.crt (replace domain name to my own domain name).

I would like to deploy my web API in Nodejs using PM2 in Windows Server 2010. This API will be called by some web app to retrieve data like QR Code and et cetra.

However I did not find a way to start the server using HTTPS and I don't have the private key (.key) file. How do I get that? Where am I missing, I've read quite a lot of documentation but still didn't get it.

It is a no problem if I generate the ssl using openssl at the server. But when I bought for my public website, I only received those two files. Need your assistance..

```html
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

//https load key
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server/ssl/cert.key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server/ssl/cert.crt', 'utf8')
};
//end https load key

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.set("mobile_url", "#");
require('./main.js')(app);



app.listen(7555, () => {
 console.log(chalk.white.bgGreen.bold('[HTTP-Server] running on http://localhost:7555'));
});


https.createServer(options, app).listen(7556, () => {
  console.log(chalk.white.bgGreen.bold('[HTTPS-Server] running on https://localhost:7556'));
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.end('Started.');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the company that I work for, the application developer is responsible for generating the private key using our proprietary security toolkit. The CA (in your case GlobalSign) should just receive a **certificate signing request**, and then provide the 'certificate signing response' that will be use to sign the private key.

It makes no sense to receive a private key from another company, as it's own name states, it must be *private*. Only the public key is exchanged between communication parties.

The NodeJS documentation contains this information:

"Private keys can be generated in multiple ways." - [TLS/SSL Concepts](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl_concepts)

Comment: Thanks! I have finally generate the private key using DigiCert applications on the server. This is my first time deployment on production server using nodejs without any guidance from anybody lol. Now I understand how does SSL work for public and internal.

Answer (score 0):

Never, I've solved this issue, I've downloaded DigiCert and I load the .crt file in the applications and it then generate the private key. Therefore the problem was resolved.